# Cannot download images from apple website?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, image

Generally one can download the images from any website by right clicking and selecting **save image as..** but its not possible in apple website https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/ , also they are using `<figure>` tag- 
*for example-*

```
<div id="gallery-iphone-6-gold" class="gallery-content">
    <figure class="iphone-6-gold-image"></figure>
    <p>Gold</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a background image. You can go into the Network tab in the browser console in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an image URL is not explicitly written in the HTML, check the page's CSS. Unless the website uses an `<img>` tag, the image URL will be written in the `background` property of the element containing the image.

In this case:

```css
.page-compare .section-hero .hero-image {
  background-image: url("https://www.apple.com/v/iphone/compare/c/images/hero_large_2x.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They're using css to set the image as the background image of the  element with the class .iphone-6-gold-image

See below:

```
.page-compare .section-color-finish .iphone-6-gold-image {
  background-image: url("https://www.apple.com/v/iphone/compare/c/images/6_gold_large.jpg")
}
```